# What is the best way to overcome multi browser support issue for old web site

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, vbscript, asp-classic

When I created my site in 2005 I used JavaScript, visual basic Script, classic ASP and visual basic.. But My site only works with Internet explorer IE5 or higher. Now I want to make it work all the new browser like  Firefox, Chrome and IE11. What is the best way to overcome this?Thanks.

Comment: Start over with a new site.

Comment: use jQuery with IE 5.5+ support or drop this idea.

Comment: I know vbscript only works with IE so instead of using vbScript use JQuery?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're looking at starting over with a new site. You will lose more time finding out the things going wrong in your old code than you will by starting over with the newest ways of implementing your functionality.